# Custom Authenticator

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have a problem with wso2 identity.

I created a custom federation authenticator connected with API
when I am using this federation as a standalone, it works without any problem.

But when used in advanced mode with basic auth, I get an error when type user name and password in basic auth step and submit this action go to to the identity federated I added and give error there is no parameter. The error I added in catch of custom federation

Can you help me to isolate custom federation?

I don't have idea what can I make

Comment: Are you using the federated authenticator as the second step of the application login  under advance mode? Can you add error logs printed in the terminal and what is the error given in the browser?

Comment: NO the basic and federated at same step.

Comment: the problem just in custome federation when useing any ather embeded authinticator no problem.

Comment: @Dev-10 Have you implemented the canHandle() method in your custom authenticator?

Comment: yes 


   public boolean canHandle(HttpServletRequest request) {
   String username = request.getParameter("username");
   
  return (username != null);

Comment: Seems we need more context to help on this issue. Would you be able to share the source code of the custom authenticator may be replacing the actual enpoints with dummy values. Also, share the application's signin configuration